# What features distinguish Oxygen OS and Lineage OS on the OnePlus 3T?

Tags: lineageos, oneplus-3, oxygenos

When deciding which operating system to use one the OnePlus 3T, what are the specific differences in features, hardware support etc. between Oxygen OS and Lineage OS?

I found older threads that say that the camera app on Oxygen OS is better, but since this information is more than 6 months old, I don't know if it is still accurate. I was not able to find an exhaustive comparison.

I am specifically interested in the comparison of OxygenOS 4.1.6 (Android 7.1.1) and [Lineage OS 14.1](https://download.lineageos.org/oneplus3) which are both, as of now, the most current versions.

Comment: Stock ROMs always have better camera.

Comment: @AndyYan: Why is that?

Comment: Camera apps can contain proprietary allgorithms (see how Google Camera has HDR+ only for Pixel/Nexus devices; OEM will do the same, just in a more subtle manner).

Comment: Indeed, after trying lineage-14.1-20170810-nightly-oneplus3-signed.zip I went back to the stock ROM because the slow-motion video recording was not working.